# AngularJS date formatting is not working

Tags: angularjs

In my controller, I receive a JSON object that has a date field:

```
vm.data.AcknowledgedByDate = "07/01/2016 15:02"
```

When I apply the date format filter:

```
{{vm.data.AcknowledgedByDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}
```

**it doesn't do anything**. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Because its a `string`, convert it into a `date object` before passing it to filter.

```
$scope.date = new Date("07/01/2016 15:02");
```

Below is a fiddle on the same. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nho955qx/1/

Comment: It can also be a timestamp integer.  Bare in mind the source of the value though as javascript (and angular's date filter) expect it to be in milliseconds, while it is common for other languages to provide it in seconds.